# nodejs selenium how to avoid driver.sleep before inputing new value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying not to introduce indeterminacy in my test code, by avoiding the use of driver.sleep (as illustrated by this blog: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-reliable-browser-tests-using-selenium-and-node-js-c3fdafdca2a9).

Using a test runner, I am repeatedly running a test case on a login form, repeatedly for about 10 times (without calling `driver.quit()`), something like below:

```
async function doLogin(driver, testcase) {

  try {
    let username = testcase.input.username;
    let password = testcase.input.password;

    let loginInput = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('loginId')),2000);
    loginInput = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(loginInput), 20000);
    await loginInput.clear();
    await driver.sleep(1000);
    logger.info("Entering username:%s", username);
    await loginInput.sendKeys(username);

    logger.info("Entering password:%s", password);
    let passwdInput = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('password')),2000);
    passwdInput = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(passwdInput), 20000);
    await passwdInput.clear();
    await driver.sleep(1000);
    await passwdInput.sendKeys(password, Key.RETURN) ;
  } catch(e) {
    logger.error("Error in doLogin:%s", e.toString());
  }
}
```

Calling code...

```
testLogin: async function(testcase) {
    try {
      logger.info("Loading page: %s...", URL);
      await driver.get(URL);
      await doLogin(driver, testcase);
```

The above code is trying to clear the input/password fields, enter new data and click the login button.  Though I have taken care to wait until element located, and until element visible, it seems I am unable to reliably clear the input fields and enter data.  As a result, I see random tests (around 50%) failing due to incorrect username and password.

The inconsistency is overcome by adding a `driver.sleep()`, after the `element.clear()`.  So, I still have to depend on `driver.sleep()`.

Is there a reliable way to do the automation, without resorting to `driver.sleep()`?

PS: I am using chrome driver with selenium webdriver 4.0.0-alpha.1

Comment: Location for _selenium webdriver 4.0.0-alpha.1_ please

Comment: I use npm install selenium-webdriver and it installs the latest that is 4.0.0.alpha

Comment: Alternately, it is available here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/.  Scroll down to see downloads for various language bindings.  For node, it is 4.0.0-aplha.1

Comment: Thanks a lot. NodeJS 4.0.0-aplha.1 was available right from `2018-01-13`

Answer (score 1):

You are running your test asynchronously.  That means all 10 test cases are fighting for control of your input fields.  Try removing "async" and run the 10 test cases sequentially instead.

Comment: That is not actually true.  In my test runner I am using Promise.reduce to execute the test cases synchronously.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the code that makes the 10 calls to the test case.

Comment: Its part of a framework (piece of complex code), and looks like below.  
    return BPromise.reduce(rows, executor, testStats)
      .then(async stats => {
        stats.elapsedTime = (Date.now() - masterStart);
        let tot = stats.passed + stats.failed + stats.skipped;
        logger.info( "summary => total:%d, passed:%d, failed:%d, skipped:%d",
                    tot,
                    stats.passed,
                    stats.failed,
                    stats.skipped
                  );